# Converting Arduino C string to Java String produces garbage

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, c-strings

I'm receiving a bytestream through bluetooth **from** my arduino device **onto** my android app. When I convert the bytestream to a string though, I get garbage displayed (even if I pass `"UTF-8"` as the last parameter in my string constructor).

```
public void run() {
    int buffSize = 512;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[buffSize];  // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
   while (true) {
       Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0);
        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, buffSize);
            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity

            Log.i(TAG, Arrays.toString(buffer));
            String message = new String(buffer, 0, bytes, "US-ASCII");
            updateLog("Received: " + message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            updateLog("error reading: " + e.getMessage());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The sketch I'm using just uses the `SoftwareSerial` library for arduino, which uses this method to send: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp#L415-L468

This writes `uint8_t`s to the output stream. Does this mean I need to tell java to reinterpret the input bytes as 8 bit unsigned integers? Such a primitive datatype does not exist in java.

The sketch I'm trying to use is this one: https://github.com/stanleyhuangyc/Freematics/blob/master/firmware_v3/datalogger/datalogger.h

I've modified the app for debugging purposes, every time it loops and calls `delay(50)`, it should send the string `looping`. You can see in the app that it gets the `l`, but none of the rest of the word.

If I print out the buffer byte array to the ADB log, I get arrays that look like, which don't map to ascii characters:

I/ConnectedThread: [-3, 108, -75, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -75, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -4, -22, -7, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -11, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -75, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, 108, -75, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -75, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -85, -4, -22, 108, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -7, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -11, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -75, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -75, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -11, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, 108, -4, -22, -3, 108, -75, -85, -4, -22, -7, 44, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -7, -15, -85, -4, -22, 108, -75, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -11, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -11, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -75, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -7, -15, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -11, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -11, -4, -22, -3, 108, -75, -85, -4, -22, -3, -85, -4, -22]
I/ConnectedThread: [-3, 108, -75, -85, -4, -22, 108, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -85, -4, -86, -7, 108, -15, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -11, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -11, -85, -4, -22, 108, -11, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -11, -4, -22, -3, 108, -85, -4, -22, -3, -85, -4, -22, -3, 108, -75, -85, -4, -86, -3, 108, -4, -22, -3, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ....]

This sort of output continues for a while, then I get shorter buffers that look like:

I/ConnectedThread: [-22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]

I/ConnectedThread: [-3, 108, -85, -4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]

I/ConnectedThread: [-22, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]

[image: garbage]

Comment: android use utf-8 by default. what the real charset in your `uint8_t` steam? please note `uint8` is a programming data type, not charset(like utf8, utf16, ascii).

Comment: You better show us the string that Arduino sends. And the correcponding bytes that you receive.

Comment: I'll update the question the day after tomorrow since it's a public holiday tomorrow here.

Comment: @greenapps I updated the question with log output.

Comment: `send the string looping`. What do you mean? Does it send "looping" ? Or the contents of a string variable which you called looping? Please send a very short string like "Hello World". Specify in hexadecimal notation which bytes are gonna send. Then specify in hex which bytes you receive.

Comment: It literally sends the string "looping", I hope to receive the bits: `01101100, 01101111, 01101111, 01110000, 01101001, 01101110, 01100111`, which is the integers: `108 111 111 112 105 110 103`. I'll have to modify the arduino code to log to the sd card what bytes are actually sent.

Comment: Please write that all down in hex.

Comment: And show how you initiated mmInStream.

Comment: Please also show how you use SoftwareSerial::write(uint8_t b) to write your "looping".

Comment: I fixed it by using the baud rate 38400 and it started receiving properly. Although once it's got the majority of the unsent data off of the device and begins streaming new data, it misses the first or second letter in the "hello world" string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong baud rate for sending on the Arduino end. It needed to be 38400 baud.